# How do I know why the jquery event does not fire despite the correct selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

**Hello to all friends.**

I use **datatables searchbuilder** in my project.

In searchbuilder, after selecting the field that is the date type, a datepicker is displayed. But event clicking on the date and time buttons of the datepicker will not fire.

I'm sure the selector I chose is correct. Because with this selector I can change the buttons in the css background color. But with the same selector, the jquery event click is not fired.

How can I know why this happened?

Part of Dom:

```html
...
    ...
        <td class="selectable">
            <button class="dt-datetime-button" type="button">
                <span>23</span>
            </button>
        </td>
    ...
...
```

None of the following events will be fired:

```js
$('td.selectable').on('click', function () {
    console.log(1);
});
```

```js
$('td.selectable').click(function () {
    console.log(2);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', 'td.selectable', function () {
    console.log(3);
});
```

```js
$(document).click('td.selectable', function () {
    console.log(4);
});
```

Of course, none of the above events work for all three possible selectors. That means the following three selectors:

`'td.selectable'`

`'td.selectable button.dt-datetime-button'`

`'td.selectable button.dt-datetime-button span'`

With these selectors I can change the background-color. But jquery events do not fire!!

```css
td.selectable {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Is it possible that the datatables searchbuilder library itself forcibly disables my events? If so, how can I be sure? How can I prevent my events from being disabled?

If the problem is from somewhere else, thank you for guiding me.

**thanks a lot.**

Comment: Third solution should work if your table structure is ok. Check if there is a typo or misconfigured table structure I mean table > tr > td

Comment: When are you attaching the event listeners? Remember that after each DataTable redraw, all DOM `<td>` elements are destroyed and re-created. So, if you attach listeners outside of this redraw cycle they will never fire as the original `<td>` are gone after the first draw

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Tnank you. But html table structure is correct. The scripts I put in `<td>` were just part of the Dom.

Comment: @cheesyMan Thank you. But This `<td>` structure I questioned was not related to the datatables table. It was related to datatables searchbuilder datepicker. And this has not related with the `redraw` issue of the datatables table.

Comment: Did you wrap yuor js codes inside a DOMready or Window.load event?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your `<td>` datepicker's elements **are inserted into the DOM only when the datepicker is actually displayed** (and indeed the same happens for the whole datepicker's calendar table and the input element as well).

When the datepicker is closed, **the whole *calendar table*** - along with its `<td>` elements - **is removed from the DOM** (together with their possible event listeners).

So, you need to attach the listeners *every time the datepicker is displayed*, and only **AFTER it's visible**. Otherwise, no event listener will be attached.

I'd suggest, in cases like this, to use the [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) pattern to bind the listener to the parent element and check the actual target that triggered the event.

Look at this snippet where I attach a `'mouseup' event` to the parent `.dtsb-searchBuilder` container:

```js
const data = [
  {date: "2021-10-06", name: "Thomas", position: "Developer"},
  {date: "2020-05-03", name: "James", position: "IT Manager"},
  {date: "2018-03-19", name: "Barney", position: "CEO"},
  {date: "2020-04-22", name: "Thomas", position: "Junior Developer"}
];

$(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [
      {data: "date", title: "Date"},
      {data: "name", title:"Name"},
      {data: "position", title:"Position"},
    ],
    autoWidth: false,
    searchBuilder: {
      // configutation
    },
    dom: 'Qfrtip'
  })
  
  // attach event listener to parent element (event delegation)
  $('.dtsb-searchBuilder').on('mouseup', function(event) {
    const parentIdentifier = event.target.closest('td.selectable'); // identify closest td.selectable
    if(parentIdentifier) {
      console.log(`You clicked on this day: ${parentIdentifier.innerText}`);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto
}

#myTable td {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.5/date-1.1.2/sb-1.3.2/datatables.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.5/date-1.1.2/sb-1.3.2/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id='myTable'>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `td` element outside a `table` So the browser removes that element from the DOM. Use some other tag like `div` and it will work.

```js
$('div.selectable').on('click', function() {
  console.log(1);
});

$('div.selectable').click(function() {
  console.log(2);
});

$(document).on('click', 'div.selectable', function() {
  console.log(3);
});

$(document).click('div.selectable', function() {
  console.log(4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectable">
  <button class="dt-datetime-button" type="button">
    <span>23</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnank you. But my html table structure is correct. The td tag I mentioned in the issue were just part of the Dom.